# Declare a variable with SELECT SQL statement to be used in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very long SQL statement which has the following skeleton (using SQL server 2005):

```
SELECT
    a.something AS Something,
    b.otherthing AS Otherthing,
    (SELECT another FROM ... WHERE...) AS Importantvariable,
....
FROM...
INNER JOIN...
INNER JOIN...
WHERE a.columnname = (SELECT another FROM ... WHERE...) ....
```

This `Importantvariable` is a very long query by itself. However, it is used in other parts of the same query, including the `WHERE` clause and the `INNER JOIN` clauses. My question is, how can I somehow save it's value so I don't have to write the whole query every time. In this example above I would like to type `a.columnname = Importantvariable` instead of the whole query. I tried using `DECLARE` and save the value in a declared variable but it's not allowing me to do so with the following error:

```
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operation.
```

Of course, that makes sense but my whole point is to perform data retrieval, I just don't want to copy and paste the very long query that defined the `Importantvariable` on several different places in the query.
Any ideas?

Comment: If this query is not correlated with the outer query (I mean, if it doesn't rely on values from the outer select) you can use it in a [cte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` to create something like a named variable *row-wise*. If the value is calculated once and is valid for the whole set (more like a constant), you might use a `CTE` (starting with `WITH` before the `SELECT`).

The following will use an `APPLY` to find the table's name for all columns. You can use `The.ImportantVariable` in the column list as well as in a `WHERE`-clause:

```
SELECT The.ImportantVariable
      ,c.*
FROM sys.columns AS c
OUTER APPLY(SELECT name FROM sys.objects AS o WHERE c.object_id=o.object_id) AS The(ImportantVariable)
WHERE The.ImportantVariable LIKE 'a%';
```

### UPDATE Compare CTE and APPLY

Check this! There are some **constant** values in **1 single row** provided by the CTE which you can `CROSS JOIN` into your query and use as **named constants**

```
WITH SomeConstants AS
(
    SELECT 'I''m a constant value' AS Constant1 --might be a complex statement too!
           ,0 AS Constant2
)
SELECT The.ImportantVariable
      ,Constant1
      ,Constant2
      ,c.*
FROM SomeConstants
CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS c
OUTER APPLY(SELECT name FROM sys.objects AS o WHERE c.object_id=o.object_id) AS The(ImportantVariable)
WHERE The.ImportantVariable LIKE 'a%'
```

Comment: That seems like what I'm looking for. Can you use an applied variable in the INNER JOINs though? Testing it right now...

Comment: @mmvsbg, yes, but the `JOIN` must appear **after** the `APPLY`

Comment: Well then a `CROSS APPLY` finally did the trick but your answer pointed me to the right direction. Many thanks!

Comment: @mmvsbg `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` are roughly the same, but behave similar to `INNER JOIN` and  `LEFT JOIN` If there will be a result **in any case** it does not make any difference. But if - for some rows - the result might be an *empty result set*, the `CROSS APPLY` will surpress the entire row...

Comment: Yes, thank you, I figured that out now that I know what I was looking for. Ended up using a few CROSS APPLY and a few OUTER APPLY statements in my situation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Microsoft SQL Server's *Common Table Expressions* (CTE)

You can read about them here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

What you do is

```
WITH (columns)
AS (query)
SELECT (another query using (possibly many times) the previous query)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a VIEW. A view is essentially a stored SQL statement that can be called like a table name.

```
SELECT​ * FROM view_name ... WHERE ...
```

often a view contains a number of joins and columns with aliases, allowing you to create virtual objects without duplicating data across multiple SQL tables.

Look at your documentation for specifics, but here is a link to W3schools examples
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer or cross apply. It makes your query better readable and probably faster aswell.

```
SELECT
    a.something AS Something,
    b.otherthing AS Otherthing,
    Importantvariable,
....
FROM...
INNER JOIN...
INNER JOIN...
outer apply (SELECT another  AS Importantvariable FROM ... WHERE...)
WHERE a.columnname = Importantvariable ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a CTE like so:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT
    a.something AS Something,
    b.otherthing AS Otherthing,
    (SELECT another FROM ... WHERE...) AS Importantvariable,
....
FROM...
INNER JOIN...
INNER JOIN...
)
select *,
       <maybe more uses of Importantvariable>
  from cte
 WHERE columnname = Importantvariable;
```